# Receive Twitter oauth_token over POST

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm working with the Twitter API and Abraham Williams his PHP Library. Now I have a problem, when I authenticate my Twitter account with the application (at https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token) you get send back to your webpage with the oauth_token and oauth_verifier via GET. Is it possible to receive these via POST?

The reason I can't use GET is that I'm working with CodeIgniter and I can't the GET data if the URL is: http://url.com/twitter/oauth?oauth_token=OAUTH_TOKEN&oauth_verifier=OAUTH_VERIFIER

Answer (score 0):

You can get the token from Twitter via get.

This is cut and pasted from my working codeigniter application:

```
if (isset($_GET['oauth_verifier'])) // <- Coming from Twitter
    $twitter_response = $this->twitter->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);
```

To test this, simply write a test page (even a view will work) that does this:

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

And poke it with a web request that has yourdomain.com/yourtestcontroller/?thisismytest=true